# Is there a bound on arithmetic genus of a variety in projective n-space in terms of dimension and degree?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose you are given a closed subvariety $V$ of projective space $\mathbb{P}^n_k$. Let's say we fix the degree and the dimension of $V$. Can we then bound the arithmetic genus of $V$, or does no such bound exist?

Comment: Yes, this is called the castelnuovo bound. For curves you'll find it in Hartshorne. In this case, g is bounded by a simple quadratic polynomial in the degree, and I think there are higher-dimensonal analogues as well.

Comment: Is this true also for singular varieties? I know about the bounds in Hartshorne, but the result there (Theorem 6.6.4) is for non-singular curves in P^3.

Comment: References are most welcome!

Comment: There is a lot of literature on this out there. Try for example Zak's article http://mathecon.cemi.rssi.ru/zak/files/Castelnuovo%20Bounds%20for%20Higher%20Dimensional%20Varieties.pdf

Comment: It's about nonsingular varieties... I need the singular case as well! :)

Comment: You don't even need to fix the dimension as it is bounded by $n$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know about an explicit bound, but a bound exists in theory for arbitrary varieties. This follows from the
fact that the set of cycles, and in particular subvarieties, in $\mathbb{P}^n$ of fixed degree $d$ and dimension $N$ are parameterized by a Chow variety $Chow_{d,N}$ (it needn't be irreducible, but it is certainly of finite type). More formally, consider the preimage
of $Chow_{d,N}$ in the Hilbert scheme. This preimage has  finitely many components,
and therefore there are finite number of possible Hilbert polynomials for a fixed $d,N$.

This is a bit sketchy, but perhaps someone else can supply more details or precise references.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it was first proved by Kleiman  (you only need to assume fixed dimension and degree, no need to assume a subvariety of some fixed $\mathbb P^n$), see [Corollary 6.11](http://library.msri.org/books/sga/sga/6/6t_659.html)

S. Kleiman, Exp XIII in A. Grothendieck et al., Theorie des Intersections et Theoreme de 
Riemann-Roch (SGA 6), Lecture Notes in Math No. 225, Springer-Verlag, Heidelberg (1971).